# pip failed to compile wxPython 4.0.7+ on Alpine 3.12.0 with Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, wxpython, alpine-linux

Upgrading python from 2.7 to 3.8. Tried to install wxPython 4.0.7, 4.0.7post2 and 4.1.0, all failed with below error message:

```
In file included from /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/src/common/xlocale.cpp:31:                                                       
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h: In function 'long int wxStrtol_lA(const char*, char**, int, const wxXLocale&)':
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h:243:45: error: 'strtol_l' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtold_l'?
      243 |     #define wxCRT_Strtol_lA wxXLOCALE_IDENT(strtol_l)                                                              
          |                                             ^~~~~~~~                                                                
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h:59:39: note: in definition of macro 'wxXLOCALE_IDENT'                                     
       59 |         #define wxXLOCALE_IDENT(name) name                                                                                                       
          |                                       ^~~~                                                                                                              
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h:249:18: note: in expansion of macro 'wxCRT_Strtol_lA'                                     
      249 |         { return wxCRT_Strtol_lA(c, endptr, base, loc.Get()); }                                                                                         
          |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                        
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h: In function 'long unsigned int wxStrtoul_lA(const char*, char**, int, const wxXLocale&)':
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h:244:46: error: 'strtoul_l' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtoull'?       
      244 |     #define wxCRT_Strtoul_lA wxXLOCALE_IDENT(strtoul_l)                                                                                                 
          |                                              ^~~~~~~~~                                                                                                  
    /tmp/pip-install-irzbquj6/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/include/wx/xlocale.h:59:39: note: in definition of macro 'wxXLOCALE_IDENT'                                     
       59 |         #define wxXLOCALE_IDENT(name) name                                                                                                              
          |                                       ^~~~
```

Not sure whehther there is some library needed. Please share your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Alpine, but there is a list of prerequisites for wxPython to build correctly. See the following link for the most up-to-date list:

- https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix#prerequisites

Here is a copy and paste from that link:

> On Ubuntu the following development packages and their dependencies should be installed in order to build Phoenix. Other debian-like distros will probably also have these or similarly named packages available. Extrapolate other package names accordingly for other linux distributions or other unixes.

```
dpkg-dev
build-essential
python3.7-dev and libpython3.7-dev # use appropriate Python version here
freeglut3-dev
libgl1-mesa-dev
libglu1-mesa-dev
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
libgtk-3-dev
libjpeg-dev
libnotify-dev
libpng-dev
libsdl2-dev
libsm-dev
libtiff-dev
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev
libxtst-dev
```

If you are building for GTK2 then you'll also need these packages and their dependencies:

```
libgtk2.0-dev
libwebkitgtk-dev
```